# Qt Dialog Window disabling alwaysontop leads to window closing

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I am creating a dialog window with those flags :

```
this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() ^ Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
ui.setupUi(this);
```

Which works fine considering the dialog window created stays on top as requested. However, the dialog window also has a checkbox whose purpose is to let the user disable its alwaysontop property, to this end those lines of code are present in the class constructor:

```
QObject::connect(ui.cbAlwaysOnTop, &QCheckBox::clicked, this, &SearchWindow::IsSetOnTop);
```

and the function is :

```
void IsSetOnTop() {
    if (ui.cbAlwaysOnTop->checkState())
        this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    else
        this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() ^ Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);//^ Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint
}
```

The problem is that as soon as the checkbox alwaysontop is unchecked, the window simply disapears (seeminly it no longer exists). Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Still stuck here, am i not asking my question properly ? If so which information should I add ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setWindowFlags()` on a window is [documented](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) to cause the window to [hide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#visible-prop):

> This function calls `setParent()` when changing the flags for a window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call `show()` to make the widget visible again.

You just need to call [`show()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show) after using `setWindowFlags()`, Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout layout(&w);
    QCheckBox cb("always on top check box.");
    layout.addWidget(&cb);
    QObject::connect(&cb, &QCheckBox::toggled, &w, [&](){
        if(cb.isChecked())
            w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
        else
            w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
        //call show() after changing window flags
        w.show();
        //^^^^^^^
    });

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Have a look at the [Window Flags Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html), and notice the `show()` call there too.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed was the problem.